# How can I compare strings case sensitive in xforms:select1 ref attribute?

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms, xpath-2.0, xsltforms

I have to provide the ref attribute value in an `xf:select1`. I need to select names of properties only if they are present in the `supportedProperties` instance which can be done with the following:

```
<xf:select1
    ref="
        instance('properties')/property[
            name = instance('supportedProperties')/property/name
        ]/name">
```

However, the problem is that `supportedProperties` can contain names which are in capital letters. Assuming we cannot change the instance, **is there a way we can do a case sensitive comparison?**

Tried to use the `lower-case()` XPath function as follows but it didn't work:

```
<xf:select1
    ref="
        instance('properties')/property[
            name = instance('supportedProperties')/property/name
        ]/lower-case(name)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using XPath 2, you can write:

```
<xf:select1
    ref="
        instance('properties')/property[
            name = instance('supportedProperties')/property/name/lower-case(.)
        ]/name">
```

What this does is that the `lower-case(.)` function applies to all elements in the sequence returned by `instance('supportedProperties')/property/name`.

You can also write it:

```
<xf:select1
    ref="
        instance('properties')/property[
            name = (
                for $name in instance('supportedProperties')/property/name
                return lower-case($name)
            )
        ]/name">
```

Comment: I tried the lower-case(.) but it gives an XLTForms excpetion
Error parsing the XPath expression. Unknown operator at (.)

Comment: That's probably a limitation of XSLTForms, which doesn't or only partially support XPath 2.0 I believe. I am not sure there is a plain XPath 1.0 solution for this. You might have to convert the property names to lowercase first, or to make lowercase properties available in a different XML element.